# Making only a particular fragment to be in Ambient mode android wear?

Tags: android, android-fragments, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I have an activity (extends WearableActivity) inside which there are multiple fragments.I want only one of the fragment to be in "always on" mode.The default functionality of "closing current app" should happen on ambient timeout for other fragments.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect when your app has entered ambient mode by implementing an `onEnterAmbient` event handler:

```
@Override
public void onEnterAmbient(Bundle ambientDetails) {
    super.onEnterAmbient(ambientDetails);

    // your code here
}
```

From your question, I'm assuming you've already implemented the other pieces required to support ambient mode, as documented at http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html.

Within that event handler, you'll just hide all but your "always on" fragment - probably with `FragmentTransaction.remove()`, but the exact technique will depend on your implementation, and it should be no different than hiding a fragment anywhere else in your apps.